# Command "auth:reminders-controller" is not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

Am using the laravel framework to create a web application where i need my users to be able to regain there password if they happen to forget it.And am trying to do this with the artisan command be running php artisan auth:reminders-table and afterwards migrated the table and that worked,but now am trying to create the controller by running "php artisan auth:reminders-controller" but artisan just keep throwing me the error  "Command "auth:reminders-controller" is not defined.".

Any idea what this could be or what could have gone wrong.Any heelp would be appriciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is because the needed migration is already present into database/migrations/ folder, run:

php artisan migrate

will create the table.
A basic user table migration than can drop your currently users table (if exists).